# Prepare transaction with multiple recipient

Tags: transactions, qrcode

Do you think it is possible programmatically prepare a Bitcoin transaction that has multiple recipient to send the amount to?

Do you think I can show this trasaction in QR code, so payer can scan it with any of the available wallet app?

Comment: This is possible, but I don’t believe there is any standard protocol defined for how to do it. In any case, any such protocol will require the *sender’s* wallet to include this functionality, and currently most wallets don’t support paying to multiple addresses afaik (and for those that do, it’s a more manual process).